# Make Quarkus health check run on another port than the application

Tags: java, openshift, quarkus, health-monitoring, smallrye

I have a Quarkus application which I need health check implemented on a different port than the application. Fx application running on port 8080 and health check running on 8081.

Do anyone have an example on how to achieve this?

Im running Quarkus 1.8.2.Final and using this dependency for health check

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is currently not possible. Here's the tracking issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7893

Comment: Thank you, then we just have to wait for the feature.

Comment: Looks like it has undergone an number of discussions spanning multiple issue - it is currently tracked in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23429 - let's see if "third" times the charm...